# Access pre-compiled Swift.Framework from an ObjectiveC Static Library

Tags: objective-c, swift, static-libraries, bridging-header, swift-framework

I have a 3d party pre-compiled swift framework, let's call it `SomeCoolSwiftFramework` (no source code access, just the framework) which I need to use in my own Objective-C static library (it's a requirement in my scenario). I've created an Objective-C static library, let's call it `MyCoolObjCLibrary`, drag-and-dropped there the framework and created a new class where I want to use the framework:

```
@import Foundation;
@import SomeCoolSwiftFramework;
#import <SomeCoolSwiftFramework/SomeCoolSwiftFramework-Swift.h>
#import "MyCoolObjCLibrary.h"


@implementation MyCoolObjCLibrary

- testMe: NSString {
    // I want to access classes from SomeCoolSwiftFramework here but cannot see them.
    // `SomeCoolSwiftFramework` is not accessible here
    return @"ObjC Value";
}

@end
```

If instead of creating an ObjC static lib, I switch to a swift static lib, it works fine, I can see the required classes and methods. But in my case, I forced to go with an ObjC static library so want to understand how I can access the swift framework from the static library.

Did I miss any steps while adding a dependency on the 3d part framework?

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that because the 3d party SDK `SomeCoolSwiftFramework` wasn't following rules to properly expose required classes to be used by ObjC, the header generated didn't have required declarations and I wasn't able to see them.

The rules for Swift members to be used by ObjC are:

- a class or member marked with `public`
- a class inherits `NSObject`
- a class marked with `objc(<name>)`
- a member marked with `objc`

To overcome this limitation of the 3d party framework I've created my own swift framework `SomeCoolSwiftFrameworkProxy` with the 3d party dependency, exposed all the API required by my code, applied rules above and made sure that the `SomeCoolSwiftFrameworkProxy-Swift.h` is properly generated and has the required declarations. Once it's completed, I was able to import the generated `SomeCoolSwiftFrameworkProxy-Swift.h` file in my ObjC Static Library (or anywhere else in my ObjC code) and access the required proxy classes/methods.

My proxy Swift framework declaration is below:

```
import Foundation;
import SomeCoolSwiftFramework;

@objc(SomeCoolSwiftFrameworkProxy)
public class SomeCoolSwiftFrameworkProxy : NSObject {

    @objc
    public func init() {
        // access 3d party SDK methods/classes
        SomeCoolSwiftFrameworkClass.sharedInstance.init()
    }
}
```

I've found [this blog post](https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/importing-swift-classes-in-objective-c-classes-some-gotchas/) which answers my question